# How to set seekbar drag in a larger area android?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

How can I make sekbar draggable area large in android? I've tried to increase height of seekbar but it does not work too.

**Here is code**

```
<SeekBar
  android:id="@+id/seek"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="48dp"
  android:max="100" 
  android:progress="10"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
  android:splitTrack="false"
  android:thumb="@drawable/ic_thumb" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions for that. You can simply increase the padding, use a [TouchDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html) or use the [material version of seekbar](https://material.io/components/sliders/android)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
<SeekBar
   android:id="@+id/disableSeek"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingBottom="64dp"
   android:paddingStart="24dp"
   android:paddingEnd="24dp"
   android:max="100"
   android:progress="10"
   android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
   android:splitTrack="false"
   android:thumb="@drawable/ic_thumb" />
```

`android:paddingHorizontal`
does not work in seekbars.